# Segmentation fault when using map in structure

Tags: c++, dictionary, segmentation-fault

So, I get a segmentation fault when the program enters the for (where it says "Here") and I can't understand why. Do I need to initialize the map every time I make a new tag* object? How?

```
struct tag {
  map <string, tag*>   tg;
  map <string, string> at;
};

int main () {
  int              n, q;
  map<string, tag*> tags;
  vector<string>   current;
  string           s;
  char             c;

  // Parsing the HRML code
  in>>n>>q;
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    in>>c>>s;
    if(s[0] =='/') {
      current.pop_back();
    } else {
      current.push_back(s);
      tag *t = tags[current[0]];
      for(int i = 1; i < current.size(); i++) {
        t = t->tg[current[i]]; // <- Here
      }

      bool ok = true;
      while(ok) {
        in>>s;
        string S;
        in>>S>>c>>S;
        if(S[S.size()-1] == '>') {
          ok = false;
          S.erase(S.size()-1, 1);
        } S.erase(S.size()-1, 1);

        t->at[s] = S;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Note: `tag *t = tags[current[0]]` is a nullptr if `tags[current[0]]` is created (does not exist)

Comment: It also doesn't hurt if you give your variables meaningful names instead of `t`, `S`, `c`, `s`, etc.

Comment: @DieterLücking thanks, managed to solve it!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the advice

Comment: @DieterLücking, if your comment solved it, please post that as a proper answer. Otherwise, OP, please post your own answer and accept it.